# Invoke an Azure Custom Provider Action from an Azure Managed App

Tags: azure, azure-managed-app, azure-custom-providers

I am attempting to invoke a Custom Provider from a Managed App in a "Hello World", proof of concept, Managed Application. I attempted using the following [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/tutorial-create-managed-app-with-custom-provider?tabs=azurecli-interactive), however the function app does not seem to work and the deployment fails in Azure when deploying, so I am attempting to make my own.

My resource provider is defined in the mainTemplate.json of my Managed App deployment and once deployed I can retrieve the following definition from REST GET request. When I invoke the resource provider from Azure CLI I get a response from the referenced function app as I would expect.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "actions": [
            {
                "name": "public/product/GetDocumentation",
                "routingType": "Proxy",
                "endpoint": "https://faraveXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/{requestPath}"
            }
        ],
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    },
    "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-995e-4e82-a86e-499522a63304/resourceGroups/mrg-Rob-20210311141704/providers/Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceproviders/public",
    "name": "public",
    "type": "Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceproviders",
    "location": "eastus",
    "tags": {}
}
```

I have created two buttons in my viewDefinition.json. Here is the entire file.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/viewdefinition/0.0.1-preview/ViewDefinition.json#",
    "contentVersion": "0.0.0.1",
    "views": [
        {
            "kind": "Overview",
            "properties": {
                "header": "TitleHeader",
                "description": "TitleHeaderDescription",
                "commands": [
                    {
                        "displayName": "Click",
                        "path": "public/product/GetDocumentation",
                        "icon": "Check"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "Metrics",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "This is my metrics view",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "charts": [
                    {
                        "displayName": "Sample chart",
                        "chartType": "Bar",
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "name": "Availability",
                                "aggregationType": "avg",
                                "resourceTagFilter": [ "tag1" ],
                                "resourceType": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                                "namespace": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "CustomResources",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "Test custom resource type",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "resourceType": "public",
                "createUIDefinition": { },
                "commands": [
                    {
                        "displayName": "Custom Context Action",
                        "path": "public/product/GetDocumentation",
                        "icon": "Stop",
                        "createUIDefinition": { }
                    }
                ],
                "columns": [
                    {"key": "name", "displayName": "Name"},
                    {"key": "properties.myProperty1", "displayName": "Property 1"},
                    {"key": "properties.myProperty2", "displayName": "Property 2", "optional": true}
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "Associations",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "Test association resource type",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "targetResourceType": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
                "createUIDefinition": { }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I deploy the Managed App and click the button on the overview page I get the following error.

> Failed running command 'Click' in 'managedAppTest'. Error: The resource
> provider 'public' did not find a valid route definition for
> 'public/product/GetDocumentation'.
> Please ensure the route exists and is correctly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling from the managed application , then the path needs to be prefixed with the "custom" literal and you do not need to specify the "public" custom provider name.For your case this means that you need to update the path to something like this :

"path": "customproduct/GetDocumentation",

Comment: While waiting for this answer I found this. I think it belongs to you. https://github.com/raosuhas/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-managed-application-with-customprovider It was very helpful. Thanks!